# Is there a template available that allows easy publishing of poem book?

Tags: book-design, publishing, poetry

I would like to layout a professionally designed book containing poems. What template should I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the LaTeX package `verse` for typesetting poems: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/verse/

Answer (score 11):

I would highly recommend the `memoir` document class for latex. It has it's own version of the `verse` environment, plus a lot more nice things. Check the section in the memoir manual, it's a thing of beauty all on it's own.

Anyway, the relevant bits I gleaned from Memoir are below. The re-defining of the macro \PoemTitle makes the otherwise centered poem title flush with the left edge of the poem body.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}

\renewcommand{\PoemTitlefont}{%
\normalfont\scshape\flushleft% Remove centering from poem title
\hspace*{0.5\linewidth}\hspace*{-0.5\versewidth}}% Makes poem title flush left with body block.

\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{my looooongest poem line} 
\PlainPoemTitle % Removes the counter from \PoemTitle
\PoemTitle{My Poem Title}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]

This is my poem,\\
isn't it nice?\\
This is my poem,\\
please read it twice\\
and one,\\
loooooooooooong poem line\\
right at the end!\\
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```