# Persian and German poetry side by side

Tags: pdftex, memoir, verse, poetry, persian

I am looking to typeset a document of Persian poems side by side with their German translations. I have some experience with Latex, but have never type-set Persian before. I have looked into this a little, it seems I cannot use my current PDFLatex setup for this.

I am looking to produce a layout [similar to this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10191/224557). I tried using babel with `ngerman`
and `farsi` and switching between languages by `\selectlanguage` as [described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12609/224557). Unfortunately, the document remained mostly blank.

This is what I currently have:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[farsi,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\PoemTitlefont}{%
\normalfont\scshape\flushleft% Remove centering from poem title
\hspace*{0.5\linewidth}\hspace*{-0.5\versewidth}}% Makes poem title flush left with body block.

\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

  \selectlanguage{farai}
  \settowidth{\versewidth}{کسی سر بر نیارد کرد پاسخ گفتن و دیدار یاران را} 
  \PlainPoemTitle % Removes the counter from \PoemTitle
  \PoemTitle{زمستان}
  \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
      سلامت را نمی خواهند پاسخ گفت\\
      سرها در گریبان است\\
      کسی سر بر نیارد کرد پاسخ گفتن و دیدار یاران را\\
      نگه جز پیش پا را دید ، نتواند\\
  \end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Is this just a font issue? Am I making a major mistake? On reading into this, it seems that only the package `xepersian` offers solid support for Persian-language documents. As I only have sections in Persian script, I was hoping to keep my current setup. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When compiling your document, you get multiple error messages telling you what the issues are. Especially you need to load the fontencoding LAE (you also want to load T1 if your document contains german, but that's unrelated), don't load utf8x inputenc and use the right language name in \selectlanguage.

Comment: If you can use LuaLaTeX, it’s much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With following preamble it works:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[farsi,ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand{\PoemTitlefont}{%
\normalfont\scshape\flushleft% Remove centering from poem title
\hspace*{0.5\linewidth}\hspace*{-0.5\versewidth}}% Makes poem title flush left with body block.

\checkandfixthelayout
```

[image: Farsi-babel]

But as suggested by @Davislor, with `lualatex` it would be much simpler (it depends largely on your needs). Here is the setup:

```
\usepackage[ngerman, bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=fa]{farsi}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
```